# How I can resolve this issue, It showing Error on @Column annotation?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am mapping entity class columns with my database columns by using **@Column** annotation. But it is showing error message.

> **Cannot resolve column 'name'**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you have the `javax.persistence-api.jar` in your classpath?

Comment: if you connect the db as datasource to intellij, the error will go away, see [JPA Cannot resolve column/IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155350/jpa-cannot-resolve-column-intellij). otherwise you could also [disable the inspection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59258612/13527856)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it in IntelliJ. `File -> settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> uncheck the "Unresolved database references in annotations"`

Second option is connect your database with IntelliJ. `View -> Window tool -> Database -> and add your data source.`